# Save Search Results of A Search Engine

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, web, search-engine

I'm trying to write an application to perform a search on a search engine automatically (search for a specified phone number on a search box) and get the resulted page as anything (XML, text). I've tried several web crawlers / scrapers but I haven't found something that performs the search and saves the resulted data. They can only get the requested page data which is not what I need.

The language can be C#, VB.Net or Java, it does not matter as long as it provides the solution. Thanks.

I'm looking for a tool or code snippet that does this.

Comment: I'm looking for a tool or code snippet that does this.

Comment: And what search engine do you mean? I find the question very unclear.

Comment: It's a search engine that does not come with an API. Hitta.se. A Swedish search engine.

Comment: Just a webrequest mimicking a browser would get you that I guess?

Comment: I think you have to implement it yourself. Do the query, save the returned html web page -> depend on the structure of the html you get the value you want from that. But you are screwed if the search engine itself changes something.

Comment: my colleague has actually done this in a way that I don't want. A program that mimics the browser. Loads the page, puts the phone number in the search box, moves the mouse to the search button, performs the search and saves the resulted data. I think there's a better way of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function like this will extract the data as a string, but you will have to parse the data in it yourself:

```
Public Shared Function GetWebPageData(ByVal address As Uri) As String
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Try
        request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(address), HttpWebRequest)

        Using response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                Return reader.ReadToEnd
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        'TODO handle the error here....
        Return ""
    End Try
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim xml As String = Networking.GetWebPageData(New Uri("http://www.hitta.se/077-570%2005%2000/f%C3%B6retag_och_personer"))
Debug.WriteLine(xml)
```

Comment: that can be a great answer. the url of the search engine is (http://www.hitta.se/) and it has a search button. you can test this number "070-421 30 10" in the search box and click the button. what will be my web request url in this case? as you can see the resulted url contains the name of the person.  in this case it's http://www.hitta.se/julius+hjort/stockholm/person/hMWZ5UUGqb?vad=070-421+30+10&var=

Comment: OK maybe I'm not specific enough. I have a text file that contains a list of phone numbers in Sweden. This search engine will tell me who the owner of this number is. I do not know before hand that the resulted URL of my search will be Julius Hjort. That's what I'm trying to find. It's true that if I put the URL you gave me as web request then I will get the result I want but I don't know that URL until the search is completed.

Comment: I have no problem with parsing the data if I get the correct web request for my search.

Comment: I guess you will have to experiment with the format of the URL. But as mentioned above if the serach engine changes its format it will suddenly break

Comment: Something like this then: `www.hitta.se/person/hMWZ5UUGqb?vad=070-421+30+10&var=`

Comment: that's much better. let me check a few others and will come back to you.

Comment: is there a mechanism to know what is the post request string that's sent to the server. in that case i think i'll get closer to my answer. because the link you gave me does work for that specific person but when i put a new number in the url it simple puts that in the search box and does not perform the search.

Comment: Well i was going to post an answer, but it gor closed, so here it is compressed into a comment: Dim query As String = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("070-421 30 10")
    Dim url As String = String.Format("http://www.hitta.se/resultat-no-js/?vad-hidden=&vad={0}&var=&var-hidden=", query)
    Dim source As String = New Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url)

Comment: And because i had to put it in a comment, the http part was stripped from the url after string.format, so make sure you use the full url there. For future, try looking at the source code of the page. The form action shows the url, and the post method is GET so its simply a matter of appending the form field name to the url in order, and formating the query, in my case using urlencode